# Created an exchange and would like to know requirements to connect exchange to Solana blockchain? So basically it would be a Solana powered exchange

Tags: exchanges

Me and my team built a ln exchange with rewards based tokenomics and intend on utilizing Sol blockchain. How can we complete this action? What is required?

Comment: You may want to start with the docs on adding Solana to your exchange: https://docs.solana.com/integrations/exchange